# Using Html.TextBoxFor with class and custom property (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can translate that line using TextBoxFor (MVC):

```
<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" data-bind="value: Name" class="title width-7" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 92, accepted):

MVC 3 will translate underscores in html attribute names into hyphens, so something like this should do the trick

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { data_bind="value: Name", @class = "title width-7" })
```

Comment: How about a space? Eg: `data mask` ?

Comment: Spance cannot be in html attribute name. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2

Answer (score 13):

For example,

if you want to add **data-mask**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDate, new { @class = "form-control", data_mask = "date" })
```

it will generate in html

```
data-mask="date"
```