# Put bootstrap style to a textbox in MVC for a search box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a search box that I want to customize with `Bootstrap` style. The `textbox` code in the aspx is:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString")
```

But I get a `textbox` with a standard style.
Otherwise, the button of the searcher is shown with a bootstrap style with this code:

```
<button class="btn" type="submit">Buscar</button>
```

So I have the reference of the `bootstrap library` in my project. What is the best approach to get the `textbox` with the correct style?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: adding that class to your helper should then work for you.  see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435842/using-html-textboxfor-with-class-and-custom-property-mvc

Comment: I'm using Razor code: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
How can I apply bootstrap style in this case?

Comment: if you follow the link I included it shows you how to add classes to helpers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a class or id to your Html helpers by passing an anonymous object to the htmlAttributes property in the helper constructor like this.

```
@Html.TextBox("txtBox", null, new { @class = "your class name here", id = "your id name here" })
```

In Bootstrap you may want to use the classes form-group and form-control.  More information in the docs http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new {@class="form-control"})
```

If you want to append the button to your textbox?

```
 <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

You replace your `<input>` with `@Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new {@class="form-control"})`

```
 <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new {@class="form-control"})
</div>
```

**WITH HTML Helper:**

If you want a HTML Helper for Bootstrap TextBox your could do something like this:

```
public static class MyHtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString BootStrapTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
         Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return helper.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @class = "form-control" });
    }
}
```

And then use like this:

```
@Html.BootStrapTextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
```